Cannot upload files thru Iconik API <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message>
I'm trying to create a basic Node.js  function to upload a file to iconik;
after running it I can successfully create an asset, get the storage id, create a format, create a file set and then fails when trying to use the uploadURL to upload the actual file. I can see the asset created on the iconik web ui
const uploadToIconik = async () => {
    try {
        const createAssetResponse = await axios.post(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/assets/v1/assets/`, {title: fileName}, {headers: headersIconik});
        const assetId = createAssetResponse.data.id;
        console.log('#########################################################################');
        console.log('###########################################################################');
        console.log('## 1 of 7: Asset created:', assetId);

        const storageResponse = await axios.get(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/files/v1/storages/matching/FILES/`, {headers: headersIconik});
        const storageId = storageResponse.data.id;
        console.log('## 2 of 7: Storage ID:', storageId);
        
        const formatResponse = await axios.post(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/files/v1/assets/${assetId}/formats/`, {
            user_id: userID, 
            name: "ORIGINAL",
            metadata: [{ internet_media_type: "video/mp4" }],
            storage_methods: ["GCS"]
        }, {
            headers: headersIconik
        });
        const formatId = formatResponse.data.id;
        console.log('## 3 of 7: Format created:', formatId);

        const fileSetResponse = await axios.post(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/files/v1/assets/${assetId}/file_sets/`, {
            format_id: formatId,
            storage_id: storageId,
            base_dir: "/",
            name: fileName,
            component_ids: []
        }, {
            headers: headersIconik
        });
        const fileSetId = fileSetResponse.data.id;
        console.log('## 4 of 7: File set created:', fileSetId);

        const fileCreateResponse = await axios.post(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/files/v1/assets/${assetId}/files/`, {
            original_name: fileName,
            size: fileSize,
            format_id: formatId,
            file_set_id: fileSetId,
            storage_id: storageId,
            type: 'FILE',
            metadata: {},
            directory_path: ""
        }, {
            headers: headersIconik
        });
        const uploadUrl = fileCreateResponse.data.upload_url;
        const fileId = fileCreateResponse.data.id;
        console.log('## 5 of 7: Upload URL:', uploadUrl);

        // 6. Upload File
        //const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        console.log('## 6 of 7: Content-Length: '+ fileSize);
        await axios.put(uploadUrl, fileStream, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'x-goog-resumable':'start',
                'Content-Length':fileSize
            }
        });

        console.log('## 6 of 7: File uploaded successfully!');

        // 7. Complete Job
        await axios.patch(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/files/v1/assets/${assetId}/files/${fileId}/`, {
            status: "CLOSED",
            progress_processed: 100
        }, {
            headers: headersIconik
        });
        console.log('## 7 of 7: Upload completed.');

    } catch (error) {
        // await axios.delete(`${ICONIK_API_URL}/files/v1/assets/${assetId}/uploads/`,{ 
        //     headers: headersIconik
        // });

        console.error('Error uploading file:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
};

Console logs:
src % node iconik.js
1 of 7: Asset created: fb8bca28-7777-11ef-847c-9a75db8955fe
2 of 7: Storage ID: aaba2964-0a29-11ec-99e0-0a580a3c0e44
3 of 7: Format created: fc22dfee-7777-11ef-99b2-4219142fab38
4 of 7: File set created: fc41c47c-7777-11ef-8c97-2a655031b7bd
5 of 7: Upload URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/iconik-us-files/a

Step 6 fails with the following error when launching the upload URL provided by the api itself
Error uploading file: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details><StringToSign>POST

Any help is very welcome
Tried everything according to iconiks documentation,
ut I don't know if I should authorizing thru OAuth2 or this method I'm trying,
just with the APP ID and the APP TOKEN I got from my iconik settings, would be enough
